# Eclipse e4 Application - ContextFactory not found when included in a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb, osgi

I have a pure e4 application and would like it to work in Java 11.

I have a plugin that provides the libraries for our product to use. I've added the latest JAXB libraries to the `MANIFEST.MF` and `.classpath`of the plugin.

**Plugin MANIFEST.MF**

```
Bundle-ClassPath:
 ...
 jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar,
 jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,
 jaxb-osgi-2.3.2.jar,
 ...
Export-Package:
 ...
 com.sun.xml.bind,
 com.sun.xml.bind.v2,
 ...
```

**Plugin .classpath**

```
...
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jaxb-osgi-2.3.2.jar"/>
...
```

**Product MANIFEST.MF**

```
Bundle-ClassPath:
 ...
 NameOfPlugin;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 ...
Import-Package: 
 ...
 com.sun.xml.bind.v2,
 ...
```

**Product .classpath**

```
...
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="jaxb-osgi-2.3.2.jar"/>
...
```

**Run Configuration**

I've updated the JVM options for the application.

`-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`

**Exception**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:513)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:90)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2312)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at com.ci.data.reports.ReportFileManager.getAllQueryFromFile(ReportFileManager.java:81)
    at com.ci.data.reports.ReportFileManager.lambda$getAllQueryFromFiles$11(ReportFileManager.java:321)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:952)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceTask.doLeaf(ReduceOps.java:926)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractTask.compute(AbstractTask.java:327)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

Why is it unable to find the `ContextFactory` class?

Comment: Exported Packages are only made available to other plug-ins which use Import-Package.

Comment: @greg-449 How is this supposed to be done with the structure I have?

Answer (score 0):

From the JARs you have listed, I think you have included only the JAXB *APIs* but not a JAXB *implementation*.

Remember that Java 11 broke backwards compatibility by removing JAXB entirely. You need to check whether any of the JARs on your classpath actually contain the class `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`.

You probably need something like the [org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3-b02/jar) JAR.